# Is there a way I can add a second path for ClientApp in C# or Angular?

Tags: c#, angular

I have two Angular projects, one with Angular version 7.3 and the other with Angular 15 and a C# webservice .
My project reads the static file from the `ClientApp/dist` path when running. I have decided to put my second Angular project in the `ClientApp` folder to run together.

```
        builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
                {
                    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
                });
```

Is there a way I can add a second path for ClientApp in C# or Angular?

Currently, my project is running with this path:

```
http://localhost:5000
```

And I want to access the second project with this path:

```
    http://localhost:5000/b
```

edit:

I added `app.map` in `program.cs` . with this code i have a new path `http://localhost:5000/setting` and i can see `Setting...` but i need see my angular project build in path `clientApp/dist/setting` :

```
 app.Map("/setting", a => HandleSetting(a, baseAddress));


        static void HandleSetting(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(async context =>
            {
                
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Setting...");

            });

        }
```

Comment: Use a different port for each project.  Make one 5000 and other 5001.

Comment: but i need use  a similar port

Comment: You need to start each project with a different port number.  Then connect to each project with the correct port number.  See : https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-change-angular-port-ng-serve-port-number-from-4200-to-other/#:~:text=By%20default%20Angular%20CLI%20ng,4200%20to%20run%20the%20application.  If you want to use same port with different paths see : https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I dont use `ng serve` ! My Angular project is run using C#. I just using staticFiles  (dist folder) for running!  @jdweng

Comment: You can run the ng commands inside a c# project.  See example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-7.0